# how spring handles Multiple login request as default scope is singleton?

Tags: java, spring-mvc

How, Spring controllers handle multiple request ? As default scope of bean is singleton and when the application will deploy in server multiple user will try to access the landing page. As the default scope is singleton then how spring MVC handles request ?

Answer (score 0):

From your application server, each thread will be created for serving your each http requests. Controller instance will be only one per server as being singleton.All the requests will share the same controller instance.

Comment: Thanks for reply. So 100 request has to wait one by one ?